# Co-occurrence matrix of numbers in the same group

Tags: python, arrays, r, dataframe, matrix

[image: data frame]

Each row in the dataframe (which I can convert into arrays) indicates groups. I want to create a 'n x n' matrix (n is the greatest number shown in the data). This matrix will tell me how many groups two numbers appeared together.

For example, in the first group (first row), 5 and 9, 5 and 23, 5 and 32, 5 and 33, 9 and 23, 9 and 32, 9 and 33 ..... so on appeared together.

So on the output matrix this will look something like this:

[image]

(This matrix is just an example, it is not according to the data above). Like I said, each number indicates how many groups the two numbers appeared together.

I've been researching this, to no avail. What code could I try, using either Python or R?

Comment: Please share example input and output data as reproducible code, not as two entirely unrelated ***images*** of data.

Comment: I m confused. Not clear to me.

Comment: Sorry guys, i will edit this post with more clear explanation and reprodicible data.

Comment: Since this question has images of data, and not data in text format, it can be put on hold as needing a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I fully understood your desired output. In the following, a solution that counts the binary occurrences of items per row and then sums up the (binary) co-occurrences of items over all rows. Is this what you were looking for?

The code might probably be written more elegantly and accelerated (e.g. by using `data.table` all the way through), but it's a start at least.

```
mat <- rbind(c(1,1,2,2), c(2,2,3,3), c(2,1,1,4))
#       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    2    2
# [2,]    2    2    3    3
# [3,]    2    1    1    4

mat_tab_row <- apply(mat, 1, function(x) {
  
           items <- unique(x)
           data.frame(matrix(t(rep(1, length(items)))
                             , nrow = 1 
                             , dimnames = list(1, items)))  
})

# [[1]]
#    X1 X2
# 1  1  1
# 
# [[2]]
#    X2 X3
# 1  1  1
# 
# [[3]]
#    X2 X1 X4
# 1  1  1  1

library(data.table)
mat_tab <- as.matrix(rbindlist(mat_tab_row, fill = T))
mat_tab[ is.na(mat_tab)] <- 0
#      X1 X2 X3 X4
# [1,]  1  1  0  0
# [2,]  0  1  1  0
# [3,]  1  1  0  1

t(mat_tab) %*% mat_tab
#     X1 X2 X3 X4
# X1  2  2  0  1
# X2  2  3  1  1
# X3  0  1  1  0
# X4  1  1  0  1
```

Answer (score 0):

In R, maybe try

```
n <- 5
set.seed(1)
(m <- matrix(sample(seq_len(n*2), n*n, T), ncol = n))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    3    9    3    5   10
# [2,]    4   10    2    8    3
# [3,]    6    7    7   10    7
# [4,]   10    7    4    4    2
# [5,]    3    1    8    8    3
co <- tcrossprod(apply(m, 1, `%in%`, x=seq(1L, max(m))))
diag(co) <- 0L
co
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    1    0     0
# [2,]    0    0    1    2    0    0    1    1    0     2
# [3,]    1    1    0    1    1    0    0    2    1     2
# [4,]    0    2    1    0    0    0    1    1    0     2
# [5,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     1
# [6,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    0     1
# [7,]    0    1    0    1    0    1    0    0    0     2
# [8,]    1    1    2    1    0    0    0    0    0     1
# [9,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0    0    0     1
#[10,]    0    2    2    2    1    1    2    1    1     0
```